# how to solve the magento 2.2.1 checkout page reponse for a long time question?

Tags: checkout-page, response

Recently i develop a new site, it used the magento 2.2.1 vesion. Now i test the site that i found the checkout one-page loading  very slow! I don't know the reason? Some people tell me the magento 2.0 vesion oneself  reason, but i think that if i doesn't correct this question maybe make my  customer feel not comfortable, they will leav my site. I have via google to search the answer and help, but i couldn't found the good idea. So I think maybe you can help me to solve it?I need your help? This is my site:   http://supwatch.com/
Below the image, your can try it!

[image]